Show that $2xy+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$ attains global minimum
Let be $f:]0,\infty[\times]0,\infty[\to\mathbb{R}$ where $f(x,y):=2xy+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$. We already know that $f$ has only one local minimum at $\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}},\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}}\right)$ with $f\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}},\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}}\right)=3\sqrt[3]{2}$.
Show that this is a global minimum by using Lagrange multipliers.
(Our tutor gave us the hint to define sets and apply the Lagrange method on those sets. To be a bit more precise:
she recommended to minimize $2x^2y^2+x+y$ on the set $M_c:=\left\{(x,y)\in]0,\infty[\times]0,\infty[~\mid 3\sqrt[3]{2}xy=c\right\}$ where $c>0$ and then use the fact $]0,\infty[~\!\!\times~\!\!]0,\infty[~\!\!=\bigcup\limits_{c>0} M_c$ )

My approach:
First, we rearrange the statement equivalently to
$$
2x^2y^2+x+y\overset{??}{\geq} 3\sqrt[3]{2}xy.
$$
Next, we choose an arbitrary but fixed $c>0$ and define the set
$$
M_c:=\left\{(x,y)\in]0,\infty[\times]0,\infty[~\mid 3\sqrt[3]{2}xy=c\right\}
$$
and look for extrema on $M_c$. Applying the Lagrange method we get $x=y=\frac{\sqrt{c}}{3\sqrt[3]{2}}$ as the only possible point. If I plug in this point into $2x^2y^2+x+y$ I get
$$
2\frac{c^2}{9(\sqrt[3]{2})^2}+2\frac{\sqrt{c}}{3\sqrt[3]{2}}\overset{??}{\geq}3\sqrt[3]{2}xy.
$$
At this point I am stuck. Maybe this is the wrong way to go?

What is $g$? ${}{}$

Why not just call it $f:(0,\infty)^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

Lagrange multipliers can never prove that you have found the global minimum. There are functions with a single critical point, a local minimum, which have no global minimum. You have to be far cleverer and apply the maximum value theorem on an appropriate cleverly-chosen set, as @copper.hat is doing in his answer.

@TedShifrin Miss the interactions, hope all is well.

@copper.hat Hi :) MIss you too!

Lagrange's multiplier does not prove the existence of local extreme values either. Consider $f(x,y) = y + x^3$ with constraint $y=0$

@TedShifrin  What if  we use  some  other  approaches. The function is subharmonic. Are there  some  research (and  possibly conjecture) devoted  to  minimum of  subharmonic  functions?  In  another "exp-Log"  coordinate the  function of OP  is  read  as $u=2e^{x+y}+e^{-x}+e^{-y}$. This  function satisfy the PDE $\Delta u=u+2e^{x+y}$. Are there some  interesting  feature  for  this  PDE?

Any way the  Laplacian is  positive  hence  the  function is  convex hence possibly a local minimum is the unique  global  minimum?

This  would be  a  motivation to  consider the  PDE $\Delta u=u+g$ where $g$ is  eigenfunction of the  Laplace operator. The  PDE can be  studies  either in Euclidean  case or  more  abstract  space

@AliTaghavi Consider that the OP is a calculus student.

@copper.hat  Yes  you  are  right  I  confused with positivity of  Hessian

@TedShifrin  Yes  my  apologies. But it  generates very  interesting  PDE.  Moreover it actualy remove  my  mistake  of  effect of  laplacian on  convexity. However is not  fruitful that a calculus  student get familiar  with subharmonic  concept?(when they  are  familiar with $f''>0$

@copper.hat  but is  not the  trace  and  determinant  of  hessian  positive(in  logarithm  chart.  I  computed and ithey  were  positive so  why is  not a  convex  function?

@copper.hat  by  logarithm  chart  I  mean  $x:=e^x, y:=e^y$ in this  coordinate  $u=2e^{x+y}+e^{-x}+e^{-y}$ so  I  think hessian is  positive  definite. am I  mistaken?

@TedShifrin   I  think, not  all of  my  comment  but , some  of  my comments   are not  far  from the  calculus  student  level. For  example  the  variable  change  here  facilitates computation  for  finding  critical point.  Now  a  challenging  question: is there a  change of  coordinate so that  the  function u be a  harmonic  map. appropriate for  calculuse  language.  But the modern version:  what  obstruction exist  against equipment of space  to a  metric  such that  u  would be  harmonic

@TedShifrin  "Consider that OP is  a  calculus  student"  Yes  thank  you for your  comment.  Your  comment  raises  some  thought about the  philosophy of teaching. Please see my  teaching  statement in my research gate(RG)profile linked  to my MSE and  MO profile. Your possible private  comment in this regard will be very  appreciated

@TedShifrin  But  I do not think  he  is  a  first  year  under graduate calculuse  student.(according to his  6 year MSE  activities)

As it is already mentioned in one of the comments:
Lagrange multipliers is not a method to "prove globality of a local extremum".
Here is a direct way using AM-GM (and I am quite sure that the OP saw this already on another math platform):
$$2xy+\frac 1x + \frac 1y \stackrel{AM-GM}{\geq}3\sqrt[3]{2xy\frac 1x \frac 1y} = \boxed{3\sqrt[3]2}$$
Equality is reached for $\frac 1x=\frac 1y=2xy$:
$$\Rightarrow 2x^3=1 \Rightarrow \boxed{x=y=\sqrt[3]{\frac 12}}$$

What is  AM GM?  BTW I  think  the  convexity  would  be  another  argument. Am I  correct?

@AliTaghavi
AM-GM is an abbreviation which is often used here on this platform. It stands for "inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean".
And yes, you are right concerning your remark:
The convexity of the function on the given domain is another argument showing that the local minimum is global.
But the OP (original poster of the question) seems to insist on "screwing a screw into a wall using a hammer" since the tutor told so.

You need to first establish that $f$ has a global $\min$. It is not clear to me why your tutor suggested Lagrange multipliers.
Note that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$.
Suppose $\|(x_n,y_n)\| \to \infty$. We can assume $y_n \le x_n$ (and $x_n \to \infty$). If $x_ny_n \to \infty$ then $f(x_n,y_n) \to \infty$. Otherwise, there is some $B$ such that $x_ny_n \le B$ and since ${1 \over y_n} \ge {x_n \over B}$, we see that $f(x_n,y_n) \to \infty$. In particular, $\lim_{ \|(x_n,y_n)\| \to \infty } f(x_n,y_n) = \infty$. Hence, if a $\min$ exists, it must lie in some box $R=(0,U]^2$.
Since $f(1,1) = 4$, we can restrict our search to $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) \le 4$. If $x<{1 \over 4}$, then $f(x,y) > 4$, and similarly for $y$. Hence we can restrict our search to the compact set $[{1\over 4},U]^2$ and since $f$ is continuous, we know that it has a global $\min$ in some box of the form $[{1\over 4},U]^2$.
In particular, the $\min$ is not near the boundary, so we just look for points were $Df((x,y)) = 0$. This gives $2x = {1 \over y^2}$ and  $2y = {1 \over x^2}$, solving gives $x=y=\sqrt[3]{{1 \over 2}}$.

I have edited my question to supply more details on what my tutor was pointing at. However, I still don't see how her tip helps. Maybe you can figure it out?

Is not the  convexity of  function  sufficient to  deduce the uniqueness of  the minimum?

I cannot understand the relevance of a Lagrange multiplier without a constraint condition.
We find a minimizing solution of the unconstrained function using  partial derivatives by standard procedure:
Finding partial derivative of $ ~2xy+\dfrac 1x + \dfrac 1y $ with respect to $x$
$$ y=\frac{1}{2x^2} \tag 1$$
Finding partial derivative  with respect to $y$
$$ x=\frac{1}{2y^2} \tag2 $$
Solving (1)and {2) together,
$$x=y=\frac {1}{2^{\frac13}},$$
with minimum point $(\frac {1}{2^{\frac13}},\frac {1}{2^{\frac13}})$,( after checking sign next derivative) is seen on a Monge 3DPlot:


Yes mathematica  approve the  global  minimum.  But one may prove  it theoretically   because it is  a  convex  function. Pleaser  see my  comments  to OP

It is convex, we set derivatives to zero etc., sufficient. The Mma plot visually confirms the minimum  at the calculated point.

KKT approach allows inequality constraints. Let $s,t$ be new variables and introduce the constraints $x-s^2=0$, $y-t^2=0.$
Lagrange's method for $f(x,y)=2xy+\frac1x+\frac1y$ with these constraints give the system:
$$2y-\frac1{x^2}=\lambda\tag1$$
$$2x-\frac1{y^2}=\mu\tag2$$
$$0=-\lambda2s\tag3$$
$$0=-\mu2t\tag4$$
From $(3)$ and $(4)$, we have $\lambda=\mu=0.$ Then, from $(1)$ and $(2)$ and the introduced constraints, we find the unique solution $(x,y)=(2^{-\tfrac13},2^{-\tfrac13})$
which gives the global minumum $3.2^\tfrac13$ of the problem.
